# Why does not GridSearchCV give best score ? - Scikit Learn

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataset with 158 rows and 10 columns. I try to build multiple linear regression model and try to predict future value.

I used GridSearchCV for tunning parameters.

Here is my GridSearchCV and Regression function :

```
def GridSearch(data):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data, ground_truth_data, test_size=0.3, random_state = 0)
    
    parameters = {'fit_intercept':[True,False], 'normalize':[True,False], 'copy_X':[True, False]}
    
    model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    
    grid = GridSearchCV(model,parameters)
    
    grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = grid.predict(X_test)
    
    print "Grid best score: ", grid.best_score_
    print "Grid score function: ", grid.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Output of this code is :

> Grid best score:  0.720298870251
>
> Grid score function:  0.888263112299

**My question is what is the difference between `best_score_` and `score` function ?**

**How the `score` function can be better than the `best_score` function ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `best_score_` is the best score from the cross-validation.  That is, the model is fit on *part* of the training data, and the score is computed by predicting the rest of the training data.  This is because you passed `X_train` and `y_train` to `fit`; the `fit` process thus does not know anything about your test set, only your training set.

The `score` method of the model object scores the model on the data you give it.  You passed `X_test` and `y_test`, so this call computes the score of the fit (i.e., tuned) model on the *test* set.

In short, the two scores are calculated on different data sets, so it shouldn't be surprising that they are different.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have few more question.Which score is equal to r_squared ? and which one is more confidential for  future predictions ? I think the second `score` but still I am little confused.

Comment: @BatuhanBardak: They are both R^2.  They are R^2 for different fits.  The value of R^2 is not a fixed characteristic of the model; it depends on the data you used to fit the model, and the data you are using to make predictions.  I'm not sure what you mean by "more confidential".

Comment: Actually my main problem is find the best R^2 score for my model. I have 158 example data. Each data represents a `week` (this data is time-series data). So I try to predict 159. `week` value. So now I try to create a best model for predict a future data. But what is my R^2 score? Is it  `0.7202` or `0.8882`. Which score should I focused for my model? If my model R^2 is `0.8882` it is good for me but if not I have to develop my model. I hope, I can explain what I want to say. @BrenBarn

Comment: @BatuhanBardak: You're getting into stuff that might be more apt on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).  What you're saying doesn't really make sense.  You can always get a very high R^2 value by testing your model on just the right data; the R^2 is only as meaningful as your test data allow it to be.  What you need to do is decide *ahead of time* which data you want to test on, and then use the R^2 value from that.  Instead of shooting for a particular value (like 0.8), you need to test *different* models against the same data to find the one with the best R^2.